# Considering time and space as theory-free concepts

Tags: popper, theory

I note the question "Time and space – a subject of metaphysics?"
might be very near to my question, and maybe the answer is there somewhere. In that case I - as an amateur - would be grateful for a simplified answer.

I posted a thought earlier on physics.SE (No 272653) where I speculated that Newton might have considered bent space (but with classical time) so that Newton´s ball would spin fine in a curved surface.

I now would like to take that thought a little further and think about the question: might we not  alternatively consider – with impunity - the bent space-time in the theory of relativity being in the category of initial concepts on which theories is built, rather than being a theory in itself in Popper’s sense?

I am assuming we disaggregate the initial concepts time and space from the formulas applicable to physical bodies entitled to both time and location.

I believe such a question might fit better in this forum.

Comment: It is ahrd to imagine that such abstract concepts like *time* and *space* can be considered "theory-free" (assuming that we can have theory free concepts...).

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA I mainly considered theories here in Popper's sense. It may be impossible to interprete time and space in such a way that they might be falsified. I admit they are part of a system that do contain theories.

Comment: I think you better explain what " theories in Popper's sense" are. Is it the  [Tarski-Popper convention](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truthlikeness/#ConApp) under which any set of sentences closed under consequence is a "theory"? Also, there is no such thing as falsifying *concepts*, it is theories (in the usual sense) that are falsified. How do you propose to "disaggregate" concepts from theories they feature in?

Comment: Maybe it's the whole idea of theories in the Popper sense that must be abandoned. What you say about space and time could be said about the conceptual structure of theories in general, given that it is models with context-specific additional hypotheses that are confronted to experience.

Comment: Agree with Mauro here. Time and space simply are theoretical concepts and there's no getting around it. .

Comment: I very much doubt that Newton had conceived of curved space - do you have something that might back up such a possibility? He did however conceive of an aether (or something like this) from which atoms condensed; he also speculated that the inner nature of matter and the void was the same postulating that an atom was impermeable because of a force, this I think where Newton was being far-sighted; but then again, he was one of the great physicists.

Comment: @Mozibur Ullah I see my question is unclear. What the question was about is something else: whether nothing in principle prevented Newton from using a bent space – I asked: But could not also Newtonian mechanics be used to make the same analogy (although neither Newton nor anybody else did so)? Would Newton´s ball not spin fine in a curved surface?

Comment: @MikaelJensen:Ok; in that case General Relativity (GR) is the simplest modification of Newtons theory of motion and gravity that is consistent with the notion of a curved space; Newtons first law is that a particle, with no external force acting on it, moves in a straight line; GR, says that a particle, with no external force acting on it, moves in a geodesic; as you can see they are formally very similar. I hope that helps.

Comment: By the way, the usual word for 'bent space' is 'curved space'; its useful to get the names right ;-). The problem that Newton is actually known to have discussed with his theory of gravity, is action at a distance; this problem was also solved by Einsteins theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interpretation of a curved spacetime in General Relativity is a consequence of the theory rather than the theory itself.

The form of the theory is based on a number of postulates:

1. the constancy of c i.e. special relativity
2. the Equivalence Principle i.e gravity is (almost) indistinguishable from inertial acceleration
3. the dynamics must match Newton at low energies and speeds i.e. reflects observation

Now, it is possible to add curvature as a new postulate. However, you can't remove any of the other 3 and still end up with General Relativity (without cheating). As such, it would be redundant to include it.